# Android Studio Different Screen Sizes

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, mobile

I make my first app in the Android Studio and i have some problems.

I use a ConstraintLayout for application and use "SDP" "SSP" library for different screen sizes. In the Android Studio preview on every devices (also my custom device) my app looks good
[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdJfW.png)
But when i test app on my phone (the same phone like a device in Android Studio "LG") the app isn't the same like in the preview
[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5adMV.png)
Like you can see some elements are disappear

What should I do to make the application on the phone look the same as in the preview and to be adapted to different devices and screen sizes?'

Here's my XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff11111a"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.PlayRPGMobile"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_230sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_300sdp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_logo"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.299"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/rectangle" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/login_logo"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_300sdp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_64sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.476"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_28sdp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="Wprowadź swoje dane"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/loginEdit"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:text="Wprowadź swoje dane" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_24sdp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="Play RPG © 2022"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        tools:text="Play RPG © 2022" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_80sdp"
        android:background="#ff222228"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Login..."
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/_38sdp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_2sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.533"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:background="#ff222228"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Hasło..."
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/_38sdp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/loginEdit"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/loginEdit"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loginEdit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_130sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_38sdp"
        android:backgroundTint="#ff222228"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="Zaloguj"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/pinEdit"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pinEdit"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pinEdit"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.512" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pinEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:background="#ff222228"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="PIN..."
        android:inputType="number"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/_38sdp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/passEdit"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/passEdit"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passEdit" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For making responsive UI I would suggest using guidelines in constraint layout. You can take help of this [constraint layout training guide](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#constrain-to-a-guideline).
Also you can make use of chains in constraint layout [Chains](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid hard-coded layout sizes for Different Screen Sizes

To ensure that your layout is flexible and adapts to different screen sizes, you should use `wrap_content` or `match_parent` for the width and height of most view components, instead of hard-coded sizes.

`wrap_content` tells the view to set its size to whatever is necessary to fit the content within that view.

`match_parent` makes the view expand to as much as possible within the parent view.

It would be helpful for you to look at the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes).

Answer (score 0):

Use guidelines and constraint the views to it. I faced the same problem and guidelines helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered a similar case but never found a simple explanation. Apparently, a more rational option is to use technical documentation